# Is there a better way to build the below string with escape characters and double quotes in Java?

Tags: java, json, string, java-8, formatting

I have the below string with escape characters in it.

```
{"Employee": "{\"Id\":\"1234\",\"isReady\":true}"}
```

There is a message publishing service which requires the string to be published in the exact same way with escape characters and double quotes. Currently I'm building the above string in the below shown method.

```
    String beginning = "{\"Employee\": \"";
    String needToFormat = "{\"Id\":\"1234\",\"isReady\"";
    String end = ":true}\"}";
    String formatted = needToFormat.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
    String finalOutput = beginning + formatted + end;
```

Is there a better way to do this? I cannot use Apache commons library due to a limitation. Would appreciate any feedback on other ways to build this with Java built in string methods or with Jackson Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this correctly and safely, first serialize the object with properties "Id" and "isReady" as JSON. Then use that JSON string as the value of the "Employee" field.

With Jackson:

```
private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static String employeeToJson(String id, boolean ready) throws IOException {
    String innerJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(Map.of(
        "Id", id,
        "isReady", ready));
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(Map.of("Employee", innerJson));
}
```

Comment: `Map<String, Object>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this may help you. If not, sorry for my ignorance.

Using org.json

```
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject ();
    jo.put("Employee","{\"Id\":\"1234\",\"isReady\":true}");
    String finalOutput = jo.toString();
```